# Get Property Name by lambda within generic class

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

This is my generic Container class:

```
public class Container<T> : IContainer<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    private string include;

    public Container()
    {
    }

    public Container<T> Include(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {            
        include = GetMemberName(property);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now I want to set the include value like this:

```
var container = new Container<TestClass>();
// doesn't work
container.Include(x => x.SomeProperty);
// also doesn't work
container.Include(() => TestClass.SomeProperty);
```

And as result the `include` should habe the value `SomeValue`. I also tried a parameterless Function, in the latter case VS says it's missing an object reference for the non-static property.

I got the GetMemberName from this thread: [[Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression][1])

Comment: I suggest reading the rest of that thread, too, it contains all information you need.

Comment: Note that the answer you linked to has a second parameter to the `Expression<Func<...>>` for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your func definition:

```
public Container<T> Include(Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
{            
    include = GetMemberName(property);
    return this;
}
```

This is the correct usage:

```
container.Include(x => x.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: That's it, thank you!